# My data can be approximated with Normal mixture. How can I find the reasons and explain this behaviour?

Tags: python, normal-distribution, auc, mixture-model, linear-discriminant

I use DeLonge method to compare two ROC AUCS. The result of it is Z-score.

Both ROC AUCs obtained from LDA (linear discriminant analysis) from `sklearn` package. The first one uses `eigen` solver inside LDA and the second one uses `svd` solver.

The dotted line is my data. The red line is N(0, 1)

[image]

Note: there is a minor jump at the point Z = 0.

Z = 0 means that classifiers did their job equally.

Z > 0 (Z < 0) means that the first (second) classifier did its job better.

Corresponding histogram:

[image]

This graphic shows the resuls of classification of 1 iteration (it won't be noticeable when compare 2 classifiers with this kind of plot so I just insert one). The amount of **normal** observations are *4 times* of the **amount** of anemia observations. The variance of **anemia** observations are *10 times* of the variance of **normal** observations.

[image]

The question in the title. How can I point at some facts and/or reasons that will explain the behaviour of my Z-score data (Normal mixture with separation in point Z = 0)?

Comment: You might consider posting this question on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, which focuses more on the data science analysis, and less on the programming.

Comment: Thanks. I did it on https://stats.stackexchange.com which is similar I guess, but duplicated it there to reach more people.